# Set circle in centre of my UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have one UIView with size 141 X 161. Then I created a circle .Here is that code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, 86, 79)] CGPath]];
    [[self.photoView layer] addSublayer:circleLayer];

    [circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
}
```

**photoview is my uiview**

When I run it's not in centre,

1. I need my circle in perfect centre of inside my UIView ( 141 x 161). And also need to set outside border.
2. And my circle is think.how to set radius at 1.
3. And my circle fill should be #222222
4. Border: thickness = 1.9
           color = white
            position = centre

I am new to iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
   CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(27, 41, 86, 79)] CGPath]];
    [[self.photoView layer] addSublayer:circleLayer];
  [circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
    circleLayer.lineWidth = 0.5;



    circleLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    circleLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.4;
    circleLayer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor] .CGColor;
    circleLayer.borderWidth = 2;
    circleLayer.fillColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:0.25].CGColor;

    circleLayer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
```